# Using functions of multiple columns in a data.frame (data.table) with multiple parameters

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data.frame `mydata` like

```
index     x     y     z
<int> <int> <int> <int>
    1     1     2     3
    2     3     4     5
    3     3     4     9
    ....
```

What I like to do is to apply the same function `fun(input, par1, par2, par3)` on columns (x, y, z), to modify them to new values (replace the original column)

The problem is that for any one of the column, it has its own parameters set,  i.e. `par1, par2, par3`, which was set in another table `mypar`

```
 name  par1  par2  par3
<chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    x   0.1   0.2   0.1 
    y   0.5   0.1   0.7
    z   0.3   0.9   0.5
```

if the parameters for all columns `x, y, z` are the same,say `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]`, I can use dplyr `mutate_at` or data.table `.SDcol`

```
 names = c("x", "y", "z")
 mydata %>%  mutate_at(names, ~fun(., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3))
```

Or

```
 mydata.dt[, (names) := lapply(.SD, fun, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3), .SDcol = names]
```

Not, I want to integrate the `mypar` information, parameter values corresponding to different column, to such process.  Is there any way to do that in `tidyverse` way or `data.table`?

Thank you.

Updated:

@IceCreamToucan @akrun, thank both of you.

I have tested both the `gather`/`cast` and `map2_df` methods.

And I found something interesting.

In my case, `fun()` accepts a vector of length N, and returns a vector of length N, it is a `window` function.

For example, if I change the function in your answer as `fun1 <- function(x, p1, p2, p3) x/cumsum(x) + p1/p2 -p3`, only the `map2_df` gives the correct result.

More complicated, by using the `map2_df`, I'd like keep other columns beside `x, y, z` in the final results, and also may need to be done on groups. Such as the original data as: 
(final result will have all columns, but with updated `x, y, z`

```
index  group      x     y     z  others
<int>  <fct>  <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
    1      a      1     2     3     1.2
    2      a      3     4     5     3.4
    3      a      3     4     9     4.5
    1      b      5     2     1     5.5
    2      b      4     3     9     3.9
    3      b      2     9     1     2.9
    ....
```

Comment: Re "also may need to be done on groups" and "keep other columns" -- really the solution will depend on the specifics of the computation unless you don't care about speed/efficiency at all. For example, ICT's function is additively separable, which you could take advantage of like `mydata[, paste0(mypar$name, "_new") := Map(\`+\`, .SD, mypar[, par1/par2 - par3]), .SDcols=mypar$name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about retrieving the parameters as required?

```
setkey(mypar, name)
cols <- c('x','y','z')
mydata[, paste0(cols, "_new") := lapply(cols, 
        function(x) fun1(.SD[[x]], mypar[x]$par1, mypar[x]$par2, mypar[x]$par3)), 
    .SDcols=cols]
```

output:

```
   index x y z     x_new    y_new     z_new
1:     1 1 2 3 1.4000000 5.300000 0.8333333
2:     2 3 4 5 1.1500000 4.966667 0.4583333
3:     3 3 4 9 0.8285714 4.700000 0.3627451
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
mypar <- fread("name  par1  par2  par3
x   0.1   0.2   0.1 
y   0.5   0.1   0.7
z   0.3   0.9   0.5")

mydata <- fread("index     x     y     z
1     1     2     3
2     3     4     5
3     3     4     9")

fun1 <- function(x, p1, p2, p3) x/cumsum(x) + p1/p2 -p3
```

Comment: Thank you, @chinsoon12, I have thought about using `key` to access the parameter values, did not code up as you did, I have used  `mydata[, paste0(cols, "_new") := lapply(cols, 
        function(x) fun1(.SD, mypar[x, "par1"], mypar[x, "par2"], mypar[x, "par3"])), 
    .SDcols=cols]`

Answer (score 3):

If you melt `mydata` to long format you can join with `mypar` to add the paramaters as columns. Then you can `Map` over the columns of the resulting data table, since you now have the paramaters as columns. After that you can use `dcast` to put the data back in wide format.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mypar)
setDT(mydata)
setnames(mypar, 'name', 'variable')

long_out <- 
  merge(melt(mydata, 1), mypar, by = 'variable')[,
    fun_out := Map(fun, value, par1, par2, par3)]

dcast(long_out, index ~ variable, value.var = 'fun_out')
#    index   x   y        z
# 1:     1 1.4 6.3 2.833333
# 2:     2 3.4 8.3 4.833333
# 3:     3 3.4 8.3 8.833333
```

Data used

```
fun <- function(x, p1, p2, p3) x + p1/p2 -p3

mypar <- fread('
 name  par1  par2  par3
    x   0.1   0.2   0.1 
    y   0.5   0.1   0.7
    z   0.3   0.9   0.5
')

mydata <- fread('
index     x     y     z
    1     1     2     3
    2     3     4     5
    3     3     4     9
')
```

Answer (score 2):

We `gather` the original dataset into 'long' format, then do a `left_join` with the 'mypar', `transmute` to create a 'newcol' based on the function and then `spread` to 'wide' format

```
f1 <- function(x, p1, p2, p3) x + p1/p2 - p3
library(tidyverse)
gather(mydata, name, val,  -index) %>%
    left_join(mypar) %>% 
     transmute(index, name, newcol = 
        f1(x = val, p1 = par1, p2 = par2, p3 = par3)) %>%
     spread(name, newcol)
# index   x   y        z
#1     1 1.4 6.3 2.833333
#2     2 3.4 8.3 4.833333
#3     3 3.4 8.3 8.833333
```

---

Or using `map`

```
map2_df(mydata %>%
            select(mypar$name),
       map(mypar$name, ~  mypar %>%
            slice(match(.x, name)) %>% 
            select(-name)), ~ f1(.x, .y[[1]], .y[[2]], .y[[3]]))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
mydata <- structure(list(index = 1:3, x = c(1L, 3L, 3L), y = c(2L, 4L, 
4L), z = c(3L, 5L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

mypar <- structure(list(name = c("x", "y", "z"), par1 = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3
), par2 = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.9), par3 = c(0.1, 0.7, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @IceCreamToucan `v` is the vector of parameters `v1 <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)`